# Having problems with custom A DNS record on Dreamhost

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, dreamhost

I host my domains with Dreamhost and want to use Amazon EC2 for the actual websites.

I'm trying to edit the DNS on Dreamhost but they have this system where there is an uneditable A record and the custom A record that I add.

I'm having strange problems where the DNS resolves alternately to one or the other. This is days after setting it up.

When I do nslookup, I get a strange result with both A record IPs

```
$ nslookup mydomain.com ns1.dreamhost.com
Server:     ns1.dreamhost.com
Address:    66.33.206.206#53

Name:   mydomain.com
Address: 54.225.12.34
Name:   mydomain.com
Address: 67.205.56.78
```

The DNS works if I use the nameservers on Amazon Route 53 or Network Solutions, but I think Dreamhost might change the MX records and other important stuff periodically, so I'd rather keep everything on Dreamhost and change the A record there.

Has anyone gotten this to work on Dreamhost?

Comment: If you can't remove the uneditable a record, you are probably out of luck. You may want to look at alternatives for email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A-recs in uneditable area are from having it fully hosted.  Go to Manage Domains > click Remove.  They then disappear, leaving only your desired custom dns records.